# How to make VS Code change language to JavaScript React when open a JSX file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, when I open a `.jsx` file the default language is plain JavaScript. Is there a way to set the editor to change the language based on the file extension?

Ideally, I can put this setting in both my local setting config file OR the workspace specific config file.

The version I am using is `Version 1.15.0-insider (1.15.0-insider)`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Within VS Code, in the bottom right of the window you will see a smiley face - to the left of that is the language the currently visible file is associated with (e.g. JavaScript). Ensure your currently opened file is a .jsx file.

Clicking this will reveal a menu at the top. Click the `Configure File Association for '.jsx'...`, and then choose "JavaScript React".

Comment: Thanks, I should pay close attention to the dropdown list.

Comment: Can we make some settings in VS code to take all `.js` files as `.jsx` files? I mean I don't want to click in the bottom right every time to change `.js` to`.jsx`!

Answer (score 55):

Press `cntrl + ,` and add this to user settings `JSON` file:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

like this:
[image]

Comment: cntrl + does not work in Mac. Can you please provide a solution for mac too ?

Comment: command + ,  works on mac.  This opens the settings in a GUI form.  Then just search for 'file associations'. and enter the item as   `*.js`  and value as `javascriptreact`.   Note: you don't need the quotations when using the GUI.

Answer (score 13):

The setting goes to config file should be something like below,

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

why not like this ?

Open your `setting.json` in vscode and add or edit `files.associations` like below:

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/src/**/*.js": "javascriptreact",
    "**/src/**/*.jsx": "javascriptreact"
}
```

I wounder to know why no one shared this on internet (at least I haven't found).

This code will auto detect your react files since we wrote path for it, it will find `src` folder of your react app and detect all of the `.js, .jsx` files as react and you can still have your `.js` files out of `src` folder like `public` or anywhere else you like.

I have to let you know, in your non react project all of `.js, .jsx` files inside of `src` folder gonna detect as react file as well because we wrote the setting like this and I don't know any better way.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the config file, I do click on the extensions in the bottom right of the window. Then click on `configure File Association for '.jsx'` and he asked me to select a language and I selected Javascript React. and now all the files are Javascript React with a little react icon

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+shift+P and then go to user settings, after that, Search for file.associations
and then click add item. In the key input-field enter *.js and in the value input-field enter javascriptreact

Answer (score 0):

Open that JavaScript file. On the bottom left You can see the language"JavaScript".
Click on it and select "JavaScript React".

Now Done:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `File: association` under settings in vscode:-

key - `*.js` value - `javascriptreact`