# how to solve code formatter problem in reactjs program?

Tags: reactjs

First Picture contains the program that I am trying to execute in the browser. When I press `Ctrl+S` to save my changes, `vscode` automatically changes the format style of the code.

Second Picture showing an error in vscode although it compiles and run successfully in the browser which shows the correct output.

I have tried to enable/disable the Prettier extension but nothing happened.

**What is the cause for the problem: npm / react file / vs code.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558193/how-to-make-vs-code-change-language-to-javascript-react-when-open-a-jsx-file)

Answer (score 1):

change file format to javascript-react on the bottom toolbar
[image]